# How to create a list containing who numbers of neighbors

Tags: netlogo

I have a set of turtles. each turtle have some neighbors, I would like to create a list of who numbers of neighbors, i.e., at the end I would like each turtles should own a list containing 
who numbers of neighbors. I tried it but some how one agent is always getting empty list of neighbors.

Comment: You say "I tried but..." Always show us what you tried. Then we can tell you _why_ it didn't work, instead of just giving you a solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a combination of [`who`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#who), [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of), [`turtles-on`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-on) and [`neighbors`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors):

```
turtles-own [ who-of-neighbors ]

to setup
  ca
  ask patches with [ abs pxcor <= 1 and abs pycor <= 1 ] [ sprout 1 ]
  ask turtles [ set who-of-neighbors [ who ] of turtles-on neighbors ]
  ask turtles [ show who-of-neighbors ]
end
```

That being said, I don't know what your reason for wanting this is, but *you should almost never use `who`*. It's pretty much always better to work with agentsets directly. You want to store the neighbors? Store `turtles-on neighbors` directly.

Comment: Seconded and emphasized: Store turtles. NEVER store or depend upon who numbers, without very good reason, and there's, like, only two good reasons.